# How to put same behavior in a super class, which extends from classes?

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns

I have the following three classes:

```
public class MyClassA extends FooA<Bar>
public class MyClassB extends FooB<Bar>
public class MyClassC extends FooC<Bar>
```

The classes `FooA`, `FooB` and `FooC` all extend `Foobar<V>` (-> `public class Foobar<V extends FooY> implements IFoobar<V>`) but at different inheritance levels. Furthermore, it is worth mentioning that `FooA`, `FooB` and `FooC` are part of an API, which I am not able to modify. In my classes `MyClassA`, `MyClassB` and `MyClassC`, I am using some properties and methods in the exact same way and as a consequence I want to create a parent class which implements this same behavior. However, I am not sure how I can implement this inheritance scenario via generics.

I thought about something like:

```
public class MyParentClass<V extends Foobar> extends V
```

And then I would simply do the following:

```
public class MyClassA extends MyParentClass<FooA<Bar>>
public class MyClassB extends MyParentClass<FooB<Bar>>
public class MyClassC extends MyParentClass<FooC<Bar>>
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for multiple inheritance, which Java doesn't really support.

Comment: Are the objects ever going to be used as `FooA`, `FooB` and `FooC` instances? Or are you always using them as `Ifoobar` in the end?

Comment: They will be used as `IFoobar` in the end. Please note that `IFoobar` is also part of the API.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are stuck with "too much inheritance", the correct answer *might* be the old mantra: *prefer composition over inheritance*.

In other words: keep in mind that *inheritance* is more than just putting "A extends B" onto some class declaration; and also remember that the **primary** intention of inheritance is to express a "is a" relationship; it is **not** meant as a simple way to avoid code duplication. (yes, code duplication is **very important**, but using inheritance to achieve it is very often a bad idea!)

In that sense: instead of further adding to this "inheritance jungle"; I would rather step back and see if it makes sense to define some **new** interfaces that better capture the set of functionality that you need; and create classes that implement those interfaces; not based on inheriting other classes, but by instantiating objects of those classes; and putting around some wrapping.